# Git Ignore strangeness

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

In my repo I have the following directory structure:

```
/
|-dir1
|    |-file1
|    |-file2
|    |-file3
|-dir2
|    |-file4
|    |-file5.derp
|    |-file6
|-dir3
     |-file7
     |-file8
```

My `.gitignore` file (located at the root) is as follows:

```
dir2/
!dir2/*.derp
```

However, `file5.derp` is never found by `git add`...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a .gitignore like this:

```
dir2/*
!dir2/*.derp
```

Per gitignore man page: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git).

I suspect it's ignoring all files in that directory and not getting to the point where it would check using !.

Comment: Thank you both. I chose Mr. Lazzaro's answer because it also includes a reference to the online man page but both are equally helpful (meaning either alone would have sufficed).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have it like:

```
dir2/*
!dir2/*.derp
```

In what you tried, `dir2/`, obviously, ignores the directory, and git will not descend into it to unignore the `.derp` files. In the above case, it ignore all children of `dir2` and not `dir2` itself because of `dir2/*` and then you unignore the `.derp` files